# Getting data from a table and inserting database in jsp

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I created a `table` in `jsp` page. It prints out data from database correctly, but when I execute the code below, it returns null in database.

I want to get data from `music.jsp` and set to database in `reservation.jsp`.
How can I do that?

**music.jsp**

```
<table border="1" width="30%" height="30%">
            <tr><th><font color='#D18603'>ActivityID</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Type</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Description</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>City</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Location</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Date</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Price</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Buy</font></th>
            </tr>
 </table>


reservation.jsp

String ActivityID = request.getParameter("ActivityID");
String Buy = request.getParameter("Buy");
```

Comment: In the code you show, the table has no connection to the database.

Comment: it is writing on code and correctly :)

Comment: Cleaned up the wording a bit

Comment: I couldn't get the question right. Do u want to retrieve values from a table using `music.jsp` and insert it back to the table from another jsp (without any modifications)?